# How to output or format data as a table in LinqPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I was wandering how to output (or format) data in LinqPad as a table. I know that for some data types `LinqPad` generates tables. For example, it can dump 2D-arrays:

[image: 2d-array-dump-example]

After googling, I didn't find a direct answer. Let's say I want to create a two-columns table for `DateOnly.ToString(...)`:

| format string | formatted value |
| --- | --- |
| `toString()` | 27/12/2022 |
| `ToString(DD.MM.YYYY)` | DD.12.YYYY |
| `ToString(dd.MM.yyyy)` | 27.12.2022 |

How can I build such a table in LinqPad?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164849/grouping-flat-data-to-create-a-hierarchical-tree-using-linq-for-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the correct solution is to use a collection of anonymous types to build tables.

The following code:

```
DateOnly dateOnlyNow = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

var output = new[] {
    new { method = "ToString()", value = dateOnlyNow.ToString() },
    new { method = "ToString(DD.MM.YYYY)", value = dateOnlyNow.ToString("DD.MM.YYYY") },
    new { method = "ToString(dd.MM.yyyy)", value = dateOnlyNow.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") },
};

output.Dump();
```

produces the expected result:

[image: linqpad-dump-data-as-table-example]

Comment: At which point LINQ comes in handy: `var output = new[] { "", "DD.MM.YYYY", "dd.MM.yyyy" }.Select(f => new { method = $"ToString({f})", value = dateOnlyNow.ToString(f) });` (if you wanted to be particular, you could test `f` for the empty string with a conditional for an empty `ToString()`.)

Comment: @NetMage Nice, DRY in action! Using LINQ is certainly easier to add new values to the table.